# Keep R from graphing a line outside of a chart's area

Tags: r, plot

How do I prevent the red line for the last distribution from being plotted outside of the area of the plot in the graph below?

[chart http://i.minus.com/jRiGxDBVw6kjZ.jpeg](http://i.minus.com/jRiGxDBVw6kjZ.jpeg)

I generated the graph with the following code:

```
x <- seq(0,4,.1)
alpha_0 <- 2
beta_0 <- .2
hist(rexp(256, rate=1))
sample <- rexp(256, rate=1)
plot(x,dgamma(x, shape=alpha_0, rate=beta_0),type='l',col='black',ylim=c(0,2),main="Posteriors of Exponential Distribution", ylab='')

lines(x,dgamma(x, shape=alpha_0+4, rate=beta_0+sum(sample[1:4])),col='blue')
lines(x,dgamma(x, shape=alpha_0+8, rate=beta_0+sum(sample[1:8])),col='green')
lines(x,dgamma(x, shape=alpha_0+16, rate=beta_0+sum(sample[1:16])),col='orange')
lines(x,dgamma(x, shape=alpha_0+256, rate=beta_0+sum(sample[1:256])),col='red',)
legend(x=2.5,y=2, c("prior","n=4", "n=8", "n=16", 'n=256'), col = c('black', 'blue', 'green','orange' ,'red'),lty=c(1,1,1,1))
```

Sorry, seems like a pretty simple fix, I just couldn't figure it out from the documentation.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try it in a clean R session. You've probably changed the `par` setting `xpd` and you've simply forgotten to set it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as Joran mentioned, it was graphing the line outside of the plot area because I ran   `par(xpd=TRUE)` earlier in the session to try to put the legend outside.  I simply ran `par(xpd=FALSE)` and it solved the problem.