# Abline in R going through multiple plots

Tags: r, plot

I have been a R user for a long time and this is my first time ever having the following issue and I was hoping someone on this site could help me.

When I draw a horizontal or vertical line using abline, it goes through all the multiple plots I have.

[image: Blue abline going through the (2,2) plot page]

I normally plot multiple plots using par(mfcol = c(x,u)).
Recently, I have been getting the above abline where it goes through all the multiple plots I set up.

How do I go back so that it just go through the specified plot?
In this case, just through the plot on (1,1)?

Thanks.

Below is a sample code:

```
temp_series = runif(50,5,6)
par(mfcol = c(2,2))
plot(temp_series,type="l")
abline(h=mean(temp_series),col=4,lty=3)
abline(h=mean(temp_series)-sd(temp_series),col=2,lty=3)

plot(temp_series,type="l")
segments(y0 = mean(temp_series), y1 = mean(temp_series),
     x0 = 0, x1 = 50, col=4,lty=3)
```

[image: Segments works but abline somehow goes across the whole plane]

Comment: One option would be to use `segments` instead of `abline`.

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Using segments worked. However, it would be nice if I can continue using abline..

Comment: Axeman, I added an example.

Comment: Is it possible you ran `par(xpd=TRUE)` earlier in your session? Try running `par(xpd=FALSE)` and then your code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318034/keep-r-from-graphing-a-line-outside-of-a-charts-area)

Comment: Thank you par(xpd=FALSE) worked!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep R from graphing a line outside of a chart's area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318034/keep-r-from-graphing-a-line-outside-of-a-charts-area)